# (Bar Button Item) コードで配置した場合とStoryboard上で配置した場合の違い

Tags: xcode, storyboard, navigationbar

ナビゲーションバーに「編集ボタン」をコードで配置すると、
編集モードでは「完了」
通常モードでは「編集」とボタンに表示されるかと思います。

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
```

一方、Storyboard上で「Bar Button Item」を配置し「System Item」プロパティを「Edit」に変更したボタンはボタンの表示が「完了」に変わりません。

質問は２つあります。
1.ボタンの文字を変更する方法を教えてください。
2.今現在は編集ボタンに関してのみ差異（コードで配置する場合とSB上で配置する場合での差異）に気づきましたが、他にも挙動で違いがあるものでしょうか？

画面レイアウトに関する部分は可能な限りSB上で設定ができれば開発効率が良いかなと思っていたのですが…
コードでセットする方が安心かな〜と思い始めました^^;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ボタンの文字を変更する方法
   Storyboard上から追加するデフォルトのBar Button Itemでは自動で「Edit→Done」のように
   **文字を変更することはできない**と思います。
   　
   Storyboardから追加できるBar Button Itemは`UIBarButtonItem`です。
   System Itemプロパティは
   UIBarButtonItemの`initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:`に該当します。
   このメソッドの引数のSystem Itemは
   iOSデフォルトのボタンの **デザインの設定** を意味します。
   　
   ※Referenceに詳細が書かれています。
   [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference: initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:)
   [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference: UIBarButtonSystemItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@UIBarButtonSystemItem)
   　
   もし、Storyboard上で配置したいのであれば、
   **UIBarButtonItemをカスタム化** することが考えられます。
   つまり、UIBarButtonItemを継承して、文字変更メソッドを追加したクラスを作成し、
   Storyboard上で追加したUIBarButtonItemのCustom Classにそれを設定する方法です。
2. 「Storyboardから追加するBar Button Item」と「editButtonItem()」の違いについて
   `editButtonItem()`が何かと言うと、
   Edit/Doneの切換えが可能なカスタム`UIBarButtonItem`を返すメソッドを追加した
   `UIViewController`の拡張機能です。
   実際に`UIViewController`の中身を見てみると、次のように定義されています。

   extension UIViewController {

   ```
   public var editing: Bool
   public func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) // Updates the appearance of the Edit|Done button item as necessary. Clients who override it must call super first.

   public func editButtonItem() -> UIBarButtonItem // Return an Edit|Done button that can be used as a navigation item's custom view. Default action toggles the editing state with animation.
   ```

   }
   　
   編集ボタンだけでなく、`UINavigationController`を使うときなど、
   どうしてもStoryboardだけで収まらなくなることは多々あると思います。
   　
   なので、1ではカスタム化といった方法を書きましたが、
   個人的には **Storyboardとコードをうまく活用し合う** のが良いと思います。

少しでも参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 私が知りたい点についてもれなく回答頂き、大変勉強になりました。editButtonItemがViewの拡張機能とは全く考えも及びませんでした^^;
詳細なご回答ありがとうございました。